# Is ModelState and AddModelError persistant in a Controller/Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modelstate

My controller actions:

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Login(string UserName, string Password, bool RememberMe)
    {
        var userNameValidationResults = _validatorProvider.Validate<IMailAddressValidator>(UserName);
        foreach (var result in userNameValidationResults.Where(r => !r.Passed)) {
            ModelState.AddModelError("UserName", result.ErrorMessage);
        }

        var passwordValidationResults = _validatorProvider.Validate<IStringLengthValidator>(Password);
        foreach (var result in passwordValidationResults.Where(r => !r.Passed)) {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Password", "Please enter a password.");
        }

        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View();

        bool validUser = _userMembershipService.ValidateUser(UserName, Password);

        if (!validUser) {
            ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", "Invalid e-mail address and/or password.");
            return View();
        }

        _userAuthenicationService.Login(UserName, RememberMe);

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

My view:

```
<h2>Login</h2>
<%= Html.ValidationSummary() %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.TextBox("UserName") %>
    <%= Html.Password("Password") %>
    <%= Html.CheckBox("RememberMe") %>
    <input type="submit" value="Login" />
<% } %>
```

If I submit the form again after a validation error, I get another error (the same exact error) in the `ValidationSummary`. Why is that happening? Thanks.

**Edit** What I mean is that I have `n`-number of errors where `n` is the number of submissions.

**Edit 2**
What I now am having a problem it looks like it is remaining persistant - even the form field values won't change. I updated my code above. Also, I am using Castle Windsor for an IoC container, but I don't think that would be the source of my problem. But for the case it could be, here is the source I am using to register my controllers.

```
        container.Register(
            AllTypes
                .FromAssemblyNamed("Aplication")
                .BasedOn<IController>()
                .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Controller"))
                .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient))
                .WithService
                .FirstInterface()
            );
```

Comment: Can you explain the question ? What do mean by "submit the form" again? Maybe you need clear out the error firstly in your ModelState.

Comment: Are you sure your validator is not generating the error again the second time?
The ModelState and the errors are not persisted between calls.
Can you post the form html code?

Comment: It shouldn't be, because I have that loop control check with the `break;`

Comment: When you say, "submit the form again" is it safe to assume you aren't submitting the exact same data again?

Comment: Well, yes and no. It could be the same and it could not be the same.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in the first line (var results = ...) and in the last (return View()) line.
Check how many results are you getting and the contents of the model state before you validate and after. You can see there how many errors are there and maybe we can figure out if the problem is you validator or a binging error.
In this way you can know if the modelstate

Comment: Ok, it is only doing it once, however it retains the model errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it was my Castle Windsor configuration.

```
 container.Register(
        AllTypes
            .FromAssemblyNamed("Aplication")
            .BasedOn<IController>()
            .Configure(c => c.LifeStyle.Is(LifestyleType.Transient))
            .WithService
            .FirstInterface()
        );
```

Its weird I can't do the based on and the where clause at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that is persisted here are the userName, password and rememberMe values. When the form is submitted, the userName, password and rememberMe are added to the ModelState automatically. The Html.TextBox() then grabs the value from the ModelState and inserts it into the HTML.

If you, for example, submit a bad userName, the controller adds a ModelState error. The form is rendered again, but you'll see that the userName is already filled with the old value. If you submit again, you'll obviously get the same error again.

Comment: I know but it seems to be keeping everything the same.